# SUMIF with criteria stored in a different column

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to do something on Google Spreadsheet from several hours, crawling the web (and stack overflow) but didn't find an answer to my problem :(

What I have :

- order price in A column
- Country of the client in B column

In another table, I have a list of European Union's country in A Column

---

I would like to make something like :

If the country in B column is in European Union (Refers to A column of the second sheet with the list of european country), Count +1.

I tried with the SUMIF() function, but didn't find how to make a column as criterias...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the number of entries from EU countries? I ask because of the 'Count+1' in the question. If yes, this would work.

```
=counta(filter(B:B,not(arrayformula(ISERROR(match(B:B,F:F,0))))))
```

To get the total of order price,

```
=sum(filter(A:A,not(arrayformula(ISERROR(match(B:B,F:F,0))))))
```

Where `Column B` has Country and `Column F` has the European Union list

- Match looks for the country in the list in `Column F`
- ISERROR would result in TRUE if it is not found; so, negating for countries that we do find
- FILTER will give a subset of results that match this condition
- COUNTA gives the count of the subset

Hope that helps!